# Should HttpURLConnection be closed or disconnected when InputStream has been read?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, httpurlconnection

My JSP/Servlet web application requires to get and post from/to a cloud database via http. I am using HttpURLConnection. The web app calls the REST services on the cloud database when loading the JSP page and posting data.

I have defined a general utility class that has a few functions in it. Each function has established a HttpURLConnection to get/post data. Should .close() or .disconnect() be called at the end of each function after InputStream has been completed read?

Comment: Yes, always (finally) `close` resources when done with them. `close` will implicitly `disconnect` when necessary.

Comment: @Thilo what about keep-alive though? It seems ok as long as the InputStream is read to EOF; the framework will put the connection back to a connection pool for reuse. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html

Comment: @boyou.io. Hmm. Tricky. You are saying it's better to just close the InputStream, but not the connection so that keep-alive magic can happen?  Maybe... I'd probably not want the JDK to handle keep-alive. Better to use a proper HTTP client library if you have this requirement.